# routing audio data from application to virtual audio driver in MAC OS

Tags: macos, core-audio, hal, audio-capture, blackhole

I'm very new to mac os , I want to route the audio data captured from the real hardware mic/speaker to the virtual audio driver (null audio driver).How can I invoke the driver form my application and How to communicate between driver and apllication.
For this task Which method I need to follow and any recommendation of existing methods.
Any help / suggestions will be appreciated.